# When close view that started locations service notification error occure

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, core-location

I have created small app that use this project as it's core:
https://github.com/dsdavids/TTLocationHandler
And it worked fine until I have moved stating location services from another view in app.
**What app is doing:** When it is started you can tap on START button and (**in emulator locations must be enabled**) on the map route of movement is displayed as you move.
The problem came when I moved starting action in a second view.
In that second view I just want to start location service and close it.
The problem is when I start locating on the second view I get error (application crash `EXC_BAD`) here:

```
TTLocationHandler
...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (OUTPUT_LOGS) NSLog(@"Sending notification out");
        NSNotification *aNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:LocationHandlerDidUpdateLocation object:[locationToSave copy]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:aNotification];
    });
...
```

I think that it is because I close the second view (view that started service) and `TTLocationHandler` still tries to send it something.
For better understanding my problem I have added project at git hub:
https://github.com/1110/common-location-features

You can download it and run start service from second view and when close that view app will crash in a few seconds.

I would be really thankful if someone can find a little time to tell me what am I doing wrong here as I am sure that it is some small thing that I probably doing wrong.
Whole code is in `SecondViewController.m`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the location manager is sending location updates to an object that no longer exists.

I don't have the time to dig through all of your code, but generally speaking once you tell the location manager to `startUpdatingLocation`, you need to keep your location manager delegate object around until you tell it to stop.  If what you refer to as the "second view" is your delegate object, then you can't let that view get deallocated until you tell the location manager to `stopUpdatingLocation`.

Generally you want to have one object be the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, and keep that object around for as long as you need it.  The delegate will get notified every time the location changes, and it is the delegate's responsibility to update any views that care about the location.

Comment: Yes I understand. In case of my main view (never deallocated) everything works fine. But in case of second view that I dismiss after start location services location manager try to send something to "its creator". My problem is that I must run location services from that view that will be dismissed after starting location service. Is there some other approach that I can do this? Probably there is some pattern for this but have no idea :(

Comment: Make something besides your second view be the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` - any object can be a delegate.  I would suggest making your main view hold the location manager object and be the delegate for it.  Pass a pointer to that object into the second view, then you can do whatever you need to from there by using the pointer to your main view and its location manager.

Comment: Based on your comment I created one `singleton` class and run location services in it it works now but I don't know how much this is good solution and I want to try that with `pointer` solution. Can you add some code on how to pass a pointer to second viewm, please?
I suppose that will be a reference in second view to object in first view.