# Can't pass object by reference to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to pass object by reference (or pointer to object) to another view controller.
This is how I am trying to pass it:

```
SecondViewController* ctrl = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil andParam:&self.sharedLocationHandler];
```

And this is my init at second view controller:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andParam:(TTLocationHandler**)aParam {
    [self.sharedLocationHandler.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    return self;
}
```

Error that I am getting:

```
Address of property expression expected
```

What I did wrong here?

Comment: Did you accidentally post the same code snippet twice? Where is the init method?

Comment: What possible reason would a view controller need a singleton passed to it by reference? Perhaps there is a better way to do whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: @CrimsonChris yes I have updated question wrong copy. Maybe there is a better way this question is connected to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940557/when-close-view-that-started-locations-service-notification-error-occure

Comment: I'm not seeing any reason why you would need to use pass by reference here.

Comment: @CrimsonChris When I run location services at second view and close it location service try to send notification and my app crash as second view is dismissed. I get suggestion to pass object by ref if you think that there is better way please help :)

Comment: I'd recommend posting a new question. Include all your relevant code.

Comment: Am I missing something or is the call to super initWithNibName missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot not pass pointer to a property as properties are essentially getter-setter methods... pass pointer to the variable... 
[check this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616147/objective-c-double-pointers-to-property-not-allowed)